# Cannot Execute program binary go-enc2ly

Tags: command-line

I've been Attempting to execute a "go-enc2ly", which is command line way of converting .enc encore files into lilypond format. I've installed the go complier suite, ran the commands:

```
mkdir /tmp/go 
    export GOPATH=/tmp/go
    go get github.com/hanwen/go-enc2ly
```

And like the website says:

```
/tmp/go/bin/go-enc2ly will then contain the program binary.
```

The website is https://github.com/hanwen/go-enc2ly

However, when I tried to execute the file from the interface, and nothing happened.

Then I executed

```
jim@Fedora:~$ cd '/tmp/go/bin' 
jim@Fedora:/tmp/go/bin$ ./go-enc2ly
2014/09/07 16:39:47 ReadFileopen : no such file or directory
```

I tried moving the file to a different directory and executing, but that didn't work 
either.

What Should I do to make go-enc2ly Run?

Comment: It seems that go-enc2ly try to open file, may be you should run it with parameter: ./go-enc2ly file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code says you can execute it with -h to get help.
Does that work?
Just a guess, as documentation usou should probably specify a .enc file to convert...